# how is this function a sum of these two functions?

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

So chui's book on wavelets has this diagram:
[image]

I don't understand what he means by the highlight part here; aka I don't really see how the first two walsh basis functions are equal to the sums he's talking about.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$\phi_H(t) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{, if } t \in [0,1)\\
0 & \text{, otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
and
$$\psi_H(t) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{, if } t \in [0,\frac 12)\\
-1 & \text{, if } t \in [\frac 12,1)\\
0 & \text{, otherwise}
\end{cases}.$$
The top left graph of Fig. 1.4 corresponds to $$\phi_H(t)+\phi_H(t-1) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{, if } t \in [0,2)\\
0 & \text{, otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
periodically extended with a period of $2$.

Similarly the top right graph of Fig. 1.4 corresponds to the $2$-periodic extension of $$\psi_H(t)+\psi_H(t-1) =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{, if } t \in [0,\frac 12) \cup [1,\frac 32)\\
-1 & \text{, if } t \in [\frac 12,1) \cup [\frac 32,2)\\
0 & \text{, otherwise}
\end{cases}.$$